# Separar resultados por días de la semana

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla que tiene un campo que se llama `TSRVDSE`,este solo contiene datos numerados del 1 al 5 (de lunes a viernes).

En la consulta que tengo que realizar tengo que mostrar x datos (imaginemos que son datoA y datoB) agrupados por semana y que me muestre los datos de esta manera.

```
DatoA  TSRVDSE 

       L  M  X  J  V
  
  1    10 3  5  5  7
  2    6  2  3  1  0
```

Lo que no entiendo bien como hacer es separa los dias de la semana en 5 columnas distintas.

### Edición

Como casi no me aclaro ni yo, voy a aportar intentar aportar algo mas de sobre lo que tengo y como lo quiero hacer.

En la base de datos con un `Select * from TABLA` tendriamos este resultado.

```
DATOA DATOB TSRVDSE
  1     10     1
  1      3     2
  1      5     3
  2      6     1
```

Hasta aqui lo que yo entiendo es que deberia agrupar por datoA. Pero despues de agrupar por dato a no sabria como separar los dias de la semana en 5 columnas distintas y mostrar el datob en su dia correspondiente.

Por lo que respondiendo a la pregunta de que he intentado a sido :

```
Select DATOA,DATOB,TSRVDSE FROM tabla group by DATO A
```

Uno de los intentos que he hecho es el siguiente:

```
SELECT DATOA,
CASE TSRVDSE
    when 1 then DATOB
    else NULL
END AS L,
CASE TSRVDSE
    when 2 then DATOB
    else NULL
END AS M,
CASE TSRVDSE
    when 3 then DATOB
    else NULL
END AS X,
CASE TSRVDSE
    when 4 then DATOB
    else NULL
END AS J,
CASE TSRVDSE
    when 5 then DATOB
    else NULL
END AS V

FROM TABLA
```

Esto hace que tenga la tabla de los dias por separado pero no me aparece ningun resultada, ademas si lo hago de esta forma

```
SELECT DATOA,
CASE TSRVDSE
    when 1 then "L"
    else NULL
END AS L,
CASE TSRVDSE
    when 2 then "M"
    else NULL
END AS M,
CASE TSRVDSE
    when 3 then "X"
    else NULL
END AS X,
CASE TSRVDSE
    when 4 then "J"
    else NULL
END AS J,
CASE TSRVDSE
    when 5 then "V"
    else NULL
END AS V

FROM TABLA
```

Aparacen los resultado sin agrupar(si lo agrupo no sale como quiero tampoco)
de esta manera:

```
DATOA L M X J V
  1   L
  1     M
  1       X
```

Comment: tu columna `tsrvdse` tiene el valor `"10 3  5  5  7`" ? y quieres separarlo en columnas, para cada dia, no ? Qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora y por que no te funciona?

Comment: @lois6b No exactamente, creo que me he explicado mal, dentro de TSRVDSE solo hay numeros del 1 al 5, estos los tengo que usar para separarlos de lunes a viernes, y luego dentro de estas columnas separadas tengo que añadir el campo B. Es decir tengo que mostrar el dato B separado por dias de la semana.

Comment: Prueba la respuesta de @Carmen Parece ser la solución a tu problema a simple vista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lo que pides es un poco "extraño" para hacerlo por query. Te recomiendo obtener los datos mediante algun lenguaje y luego agrupar por día.

De todas formas, para hacerlo mediante una query, se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
> SELECT * FROM test;

dia  valor
===  =====
1    1
1    2
1    1
1    2
2    1
2    3
2    1
2    1
2    1
1    3
5    1
5    3

> SELECT valor, SUM(dia=1) AS dia_1, SUM(dia=2) AS dia_2, SUM(dia=3) AS dia_3, SUM(dia=4) AS dia_4, SUM(dia=5) AS dia_5
  FROM test
  GROUP BY valor;


valor dia_1 dia_2 dia_3 dia_4 dia_5
===== ===== ===== ===== ===== =====
1     2     4     0     0     1
2     2     0     0     0     0
3     1     1     0     0     1
```

En resumen, genero una columna para cada día y sumo la cantidad de filas que existen cuando agrupo mediante el campo `valor`. Es un enfoque bastante simple, que puede escalar fácilmente para sumar, sacar promedios, desv. estandar, etc, de un valor.

**UPDATE:**

de acuerdo a los comentarios de @Andoni Alda necesita que se muestre un tercer campo. Asumiendo los siguientes datos:

```
dia valor valor_b
=== ===== =======
1    1     b1
1    2     b2
1    1     b3
1    2     b3
2    1     b2
2    3     b1
2    1     b1
2    1     b1
2    1     b2
1    3     b3
5    1     b4
5    3     b1

> SELECT valor, 
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=1, valor_b, NULL)) dia_1,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=2, valor_b, NULL)) dia_2,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=3, valor_b, NULL)) dia_3,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=4, valor_b, NULL)) dia_4,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=5, valor_b, NULL)) dia_5
FROM test
GROUP BY valor;

valor dia_1 dia_2 dia_3 dia_4 dia_5
===== ===== ===== ===== ===== =====
1     b1,b3 b2,b1 NULL  NULL  b4
2     b3,b2 NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL
3     b3    b1    NULL  NULL  b1
```

Ahora, insisto en que para un reporte obtenido directo desde SQL es util, pero si necesitas mostrarlo en una pagina web/aplicación/etc, es mejor hacer esta agrupación en el lenguaje de programación (haciendo map/reduce, por ejemplo)

saludos

Comment: El problema que tengo si lo hago con php es que tengo que usar como clave 10 campos, esto me parece demasiado pesado (con el conocimiento de php que tengo yo para hacerlo). Acepto respuestas en php si es mas correcto hacerlo de esta forma.

Comment: 10 campos es NADA con el nivel de procesamiento actual. Ahora mismo estoy procesando un millon de registros y guardo en memoria un array con las keys para evitar duplicidad

Comment: de todas formas, esta query creo que da solución a tu problema, no?

Comment: Interesante, me gustaria saber la solución php si es posible.

Comment: Ahora la estoy probando.

Comment: El dato que muestro en dia es la suma de las veces que ´valor´ esta en ese dia, como puedo hacer para que, en vez de mostrar las veces que aparece, muestre otro campo (una tercera columna) ?

Comment: otro campo? quieres agrupar por `valor`, pero que muestre algún resumen sobre un campo `B`?

Comment: Si o eso creo que es lo correcto, que me muestre el dato B cuando en la columna del dia correcto con su campo A correcto, no se cuanto de complejo sera, pero como he dicho, si resulta mas sencillo hacerlo en php, tambien acepto respuestas php

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar cómo está constituida tu tabla o tus tablas (aquella/s de donde sacas tus datos) y cuáles son las columnas que quieres relacionar y/o presentar en el resultado?

Comment: @A.Cedano La consulta es sobre una unica tabla, me gustaria poder dar información sobre la tabla pero por motivos de privacidad no se ni si puedo por lo que intentare decirtelo resumirlo. En la tabla tengo 10 campos que constituyen la clave junto el campo dia de la semana que es parte de la clave. Existe un 12º campo que este contiene la informacion que quiero mostrar. Bien pues ahora mismo estoy mostrando todos los campos + el dia de la semana + la informacion en filas distintas por cada dia de la semana, el objetivo es mostrar la clave y separar los dias en 5 columnas y en cada una mostrar e

Comment: @AndoniAlda actualicé la respuesta

Comment: Ahora si lista de manera correcta, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

He tratado de **reproducir** tu complicado problema y creo que se puede resolver de la siguiente manera, si he entendido bien.

El resultado vendría en un array de dos dimensiones, el cual podrías leer fácilmente  en la aplicación que manejará o presentará los datos.

Ejemplo de resultado del dato_a con valor `1`:

```
1_10|2_3|3_5|4_6|5_3
```

- El símbolo `|` sería el separador de días de la semana: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
- El símbolo `_` sería el separador entre el día de la semana y el valor de `dato_2`

Ese tipo de array se podría leer con suma facilidad en PHP, usando un doble [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php), lo mismo en cualquier lenguaje de programación.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a5f13/26)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla_complicada
    (`dato_a` int, `dato_b` int, `tsrvdse` int)
;

INSERT INTO tabla_complicada
    (`dato_a`, `dato_b`, `tsrvdse`)
VALUES
    (1, 10,1),
    (1, 3, 2),
    (1, 5, 3),
    (1, 6, 4),
    (1, 3, 5),
    (2, 6,1),
    (2, 2, 2),
    (2, 3, 3),
    (2, 1, 4),
    (2, 0, 5);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
  dato_a, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(tsrvdse,'_',dato_b ORDER BY tsrvdse ASC SEPARATOR '|' )
  as columna_complicada
FROM
  tabla_complicada 
GROUP BY dato_a
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a5f13/26/0)**:

```
| dato_a |   columna_complicada |
|--------|----------------------|
|      1 | 1_10|2_3|3_5|4_6|5_3 |
|      2 |  1_6|2_2|3_3|4_1|5_0 |
```

Comment: Curiosa solución, es totalmente valida, pero creo que la solucion de @PabloAlcantar me viene mejor. Muchas gracias de todos modos.

Comment: @AndoniAlda De ese se trata, de encontrar una solución, aunque, sobre todo, si se trata del manejo de muchos datos, se recomienda siempre obtenerlos de la forma más simple posible y organizarlos al momento de presentarlos. Pero eso ya depende de cada uno. No es lo mismo obtener los datos de la forma más plana posible que hacer consultas condicionales dentro de la misma base de datos y luego transportar esos datos formateados (más pesados). Es como cuando compras algo, no es lo mismo recibirlo nuevo en su paquete que ya abierto... Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Te copio aquí la respuesta que había puesto en la otra pregunta, para evitar duplicados. Se ve que estábamos contestando a la vez en ambas preguntas.

Sin ver como está la tabla, y si he entendido bien lo que quieres, quizás te sirva esta query más sencilla:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.PK, T.DIA_SEM, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM MI_TABLA T
GROUP BY T.DIA_SEM
```

con esto debería listarte todos los datos agrupados por día de la semana y con diferente PK, ya los ordenas como prefieras. Espero que te funcione.