# Problemas con group concat SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

A partir de mi anterior [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68164/separar-resultados-por-d%C3%ADas-de-la-semana) y con la solución que me aportaron la sentecia funcionaba correctamente.

Esta era la sentencia correcta

```
SELECT valor, 
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=1, valor_b, NULL)) dia_1,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=2, valor_b, NULL)) dia_2,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=3, valor_b, NULL)) dia_3,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=4, valor_b, NULL)) dia_4,
  group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=5, valor_b, NULL)) dia_5
FROM test
GROUP BY valor;
```

En este caso, el problema es el siguiente. En vez de mostrar `valor_b` tengo que contar cuantas veces aparece `valor_b` por dia.

Para ello simplemente cambie la parte del codigo en la que digo que muestre `valor_b`:

```
 SELECT valor, 
      group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=1, count(valor_b), NULL)) dia_1,
      group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=2, count(valor_b), NULL)) dia_2,
      group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=3, count(valor_b), NULL)) dia_3,
      group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=4, count(valor_b), NULL)) dia_4,
      group_concat(DISTINCT IF(dia=5, count(valor_b), NULL)) dia_5
    FROM test
    GROUP BY valor;
```

Me devuelve el siguiente error:

> 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Esta seria una estructura de datos valida para la tabla de pruebas

```
dia valor valor_b
=== ===== =======
1    1     b1
1    2     b2
1    1     b3
1    2     b3
2    1     b2
2    3     b1
2    1     b1
2    1     b1
2    1     b2
1    3     b3
5    1     b4
5    3     b1
```

Comment: No se entiende bien... Te di una respuesta en la anterior pregunta, pero en ella la estructura de datos inicial era diferente. Tenías valor_a, valor_b y otro valor que eran los días de Lunes a Viernes numerados del 1 al 5, sospecho que lo puedes hacer con facilidad del [modo que te respondía en la otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/68202/29967) pero no entiendo bien qué es lo que quieres sumar. Creo que te has liado un poco con los datos y que si volvemos a la forma original en que están tus datos la solución sería más fácil de lo que crees.

Comment: @A.Cedano es que en la anterior pregunta usaba otra estructura de datos,para esa pregunta, tu solucion era valida. En este caso necesitaba saber el numero de veces que aparece el valor_b y no cual es el valor_b en esa aparicion. Es un poco complejo, tanto que ni yo mismo comprendo muy bien lo que tengo que hacer. Pero al fin y al cabo, hago lo que me mandan.

Comment: Entiendo, pero aquí la cuestión es la siguiente: **¿cómo están realmente tus datos en la base de datos?** me refiero a los datos originales, sería interesante que indicaras cómo están guardados los datos. Porque creo que has tomado una solución por las ramas y por eso se te ha complicado el asunto.

Comment: @A.Cedano no se si la solución esta cogida por las ramas o no, pero bueno por ahora funciona bien, en cualquier caso, si veo que realmente esto no me funciona y que necesito que para una solución tengo que mostrar la estructura no dudare en volver a pedir ayuda y aclarar la estructura de mi base de datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He hecho la misma [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864424/sql-count-value-per-day-return-error/43864556#43864552) con mi otra cuenta en el sitio en ingles.

El sql correcto es el siguiente,

```
SELECT valor, 
      sum(IF(dia=1, 1, NULL)) dia_1,
      sum(IF(dia=2, 1, NULL)) dia_2,
      sum(IF(dia=3, 1, NULL)) dia_3,
      sum(IF(dia=4, 1, NULL)) dia_4,
      sum(IF(dia=5, 1, NULL)) dia_5
    FROM test
    GROUP BY valor;
```

Cada vez que aparece un dia se va sumando y da como resultado el ´count(valor_b)´

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que te interesa es sumar cuantas veces aparece el valor b, ¿que tal si pruebas con la función `CASE when` en lugar de `if`?

Algo así, teniendo en cuenta los casos en los que quieras agregar en función del valor_b:

```
select  
case when valor_b=b1 then sum(dia) else 
case when valor_b=b2 then ...
```

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que tengo que hacer 5 columnas por día en un solo `case` no podría hacerlo, lo tendría que dividir en 5 distintos y sin probarlo supongo que funcionaria, pero por ahora mi solución es valida y funciona.